# How can I prove that a specific instance no longer exists using RSpec?

Tags: ruby, object, rspec, instance

I'm writing unit tests in RSpec to check that an instance that was created no longer exists after a method moves or deletes it.

For example, I have an Airport class and a Plane class, and airport = Airport.new initializes with a Plane.new instance stored. When the #takeoff method is run, Plane.new is stored somewhere else or #pop'ped.

**How can I prove that this exact instance of Plane.new is not included in airport? Is there a way to capture the id of the object that a method acts on?**

The test I'm thinking of would go something like this:

```
describe Airport do
  it "confirms plane is not there after #takeoff" do
    airport = Airport.new
    airport.takeoff
    expect(airport).not_to include(*ID OF PLANE MOVED/POPPED*)
  end
end
```

In the future, Airport could be initialized with any number of planes, so I believe it will be necessary to use the id to confirm, but I'd be happy to hear otherwise.

Comment: have you looked at the object_id method? https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Object.html#method-i-object_id

Answer (score 3):

Normally unit tests test public APIs, so the question should be: "Is there way for Airport to tell us what planes are on the ground". And there has to be a method like that, if that's an important piece of information. For example you might have a methods called `planes` and then you just check to see if particular instance is included in that collection:

```
expect(airport.planes).not_to include(plane)
```

An alternative approach might be that plane has a reference to the airport where it's located right now and after take off it would be set nil. So you'd end up checking that reference:

```
expect(plane.airport).to be_nil
```

But anyways it's all about data modeling, not about test frameworks

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using object_id as mentioned in my comment.
My rspec skills are a little rusty, but hopefully you get the idea.

```
require 'rspec'

class Plane 
    def initialize(some_property)
        @some_property = some_property
    end
end

class Airport
    attr_reader :planes_ready_for_takeoff, :planes_in_fight
    def initialize()
        @planes_ready_for_takeoff = [Plane.new("plane_foo"), Plane.new("plane_bar")]
        @planes_in_fight = []
    end
    def takeoff()
        @planes_in_fight << @planes_ready_for_takeoff.shift
    end
end

describe "Airport" do
  before(:context) do 
    @airport =  Airport.new 
    @first_plane = @airport.planes_ready_for_takeoff.first
  end
  it "confirms a plane is ready for takeoff" do
    expect(@airport.planes_ready_for_takeoff.map { |p| p.object_id}).to include(@first_plane.object_id)
end
describe "#takeoff" do 
    it "remove the first plane from the list of planes ready to take off" do 
        @airport.takeoff 
        expect(@airport.planes_ready_for_takeoff.map { |p| p.object_id}).not_to include(@first_plane.object_id)
    end
  end
end
```

BTW,  I don't think you even need to to the map to object_id because I think include uses `==` which should check for the exact object.

Comment: Given that property exists and is public, one can just do `expect(@airport.planes_ready_for_takeoff).to include(@first_plane)`, no need for checking the id.

Comment: true,  I was just going to add that as a comment